# Real time processing millions rows

Tags: sql, mongodb, apache-spark, real-time

In my application one table has entries around 20 millions row and that growing exponentially . We need to generate different types of report on that data , which involves following operations

- fetch all record group them based on custom criteria
- sort them
- process them and generate report

this is time consuming task , we are trying the approach of batch processing but to generate data for one report it takes 1 hr.

I was thinking of solving this problem using different methods

- Do proper indexing of the table
- Write a Async task which will process each new entry in table and put data in reporting table (in some cases this is not possible)
- Use mongodb - pre aggregated index with apache spark

Is it possible to get real time report , and how can i approach toward it please guide.

Comment: Mongodb has nothing to do with the Mongols.

Comment: @Spade That's what they want you to think

Comment: @ganeshp you haven't indicated what your current DBMS is? Are you using Oracle, MySQL or Postgres? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Plus, it might be pretty helpful to tell us how exactly you do it now and how your documents and indices look like – in case you use MongoDB already.